# Does setter method return type have to be void?

Tags: jsf

I change setter method return type to an object for ease eg: `obj.setValue(newVal).setName(newName).setId(newId);`

but after this change tomcat gives

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:

```
    /WEB-INF/flows/materialorder/newOrder.xhtml @99,182 
value="#{materailOrdService.mofEntity.nmExplanation.value}": 
Property 'value' not writable on type tr.com.hydron.softexpert.order.model.MainFormEntity$MofField
```

To get rid of this exception I changed modifier from private to
    public but still getting the same error. So I have two questions;

1. Does jsf need setter for modifying the object even if it's modifier
   is public?
2. Does setter method return type have to be void for jsf
   modifying an object value?

Here is my object class

```
public static class MofField implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Object value;
    ...    


    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public MofField setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
        return this;
    }       
    ...     
}
```

**edit:**
here is my xhtml code:

```
<p:inputTextarea valueChangeListener="#{materailOrdService.onExplanationChange}"  value="#{materailOrdService.mofEntity.nmExplanation.value}" rows="3" cols="38" >
    <p:ajax event="valueChange" global="false" immediate="true" partialSubmit="true" process="@this"  />
</p:inputTextarea>
```

Comment: Changing a property declaration from `private` to `public` without its getter method does not make it to be accessed by EL like `#{bean.value}` because this EL, in this example, refers to the corresponding getter method `getValue()` and not the field `value` itself. If you are using input components, you will need both a getter and a setter for a field complying the Java bean specification where a setter method cannot have a return type or otherwise, it cannot be said to be a write-only method.

Comment: This looks like an answer could you please post it as an answer

Comment: I always leave answers to experts which I am not :)

Comment: @Tiny I don't consider myself an expert at all, but note that answering is a good way to learn. If my answer is incorrect, people will prove me wrong, then that mean I learned something new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does jsf need setter for modifying the object even if it's modifier is
>   public?

Short answer : Yes.

By convention, each field of a Bean should be private and be accessed/mutated by there respective getters and setters.

Changing the field to public won't change anything, as when you type in the field name in your EL code, the server will search for the `setFieldName(param)` or `getFieldName` or `isFieldName` if your field is a boolean.

> Does setter method return type have to be void for jsf modifying an
>   object value?

Yes, the server will search void a signature containing `void`. Try it and see.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of the second because it's not directly stated in the JavaBean Specification. The first one it is.

Comment: I didn't find any reason but, after I restore setter return type to void it start to work again.